# Overriding Bootstrap themes in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to override Bootstrap's themes in my laravel project. I am able to change the variables in app.css by changing them in in the app.scss file, like so:

app.scss:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

$primary: black;
$success: black;

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "custom";
```

which changes the app.css to:

```
:root {
  --blue: #3490dc;
  --indigo: #6574cd;
  --purple: #9561e2;
  --pink: #f66d9b;
  --red: #e3342f;
  --orange: #f6993f;
  --yellow: #ffed4a;
  --green: #38c172;
  --teal: #4dc0b5;
  --cyan: #6cb2eb;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #6c757d;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;

  // Important
  --primary: black;

  --secondary: #6c757d;

  // Important
  --success: black;

  --info: #6cb2eb;
  --warning: #ffed4a;
  --danger: #e3342f;
  --light: #f8f9fa;
  --dark: #343a40;
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
  --font-family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

I know for a fact that it is getting changed, even after doing a cache refresh on chrome, because when I inspect the root, this is what I find:
[image]

So for whatever reason, the fontawesome stylesheet is overriding my bootstrap stylesheet. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is what my app.blade.php file looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-QMu+Y+eu45Nfr9fmFOlw8EqjiUreChmoQ7k7C1pFNO8hEbGv9yzsszTmz+RzwyCh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

    <title>Hello, world!!</title>
</head>

<body class="trivalo-background">

@yield('layout')

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7d75c9db00.js"></script>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Even if i comment out everything that has to do with the fontawesome, it still wont show. Im sure its something obvious but I could really use some help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42138503/5581565 am out of flags

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The answer accepted in that post is to refresh the cache and reload the page. i very clearly stated that I tried this and it did not work. Thank you.

Comment: Trying placing `@import "custom";` before `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
` since you're compiling to the same file and the browser will read the first style rule

Comment: Did not work. It is not looking in the custom.scss for changes. It is happening in the app.scss. I tried placing the same thing in the custom.scss pllus some other stuff for testing, but nothing changed.

Comment: I know it's an ugly and hackish solution but could you add !important on styles that don't work?

Comment: "So for whatever reason, the fontawesome stylesheet is overriding my bootstrap stylesheet" "Even if i comment out everything that has to do with the fontawesome, it still wont show" These are contradictory statements. Your browser inspector should be able to show you what stylesheet a rule is being imported from.